# Is it a semantic or syntax error to not have an argument list after a name prefixed by the template keyword?

Tags: c++, syntax, semantics

According to [[temp.names]p6](https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.names#6), "A name prefixed by the keyword template shall be followed by a template argument list or refer to a class template...".

The example provided shows

```
A<T> a;
a.template f<>(t);                    // OK, calls template
a.template f(t);                      // error: not a template-id
```

Would the error line be categorized as a semantic error or a syntax error? Since the standard states that a name must be followed up by an argument list, not that the name must be a valid template name, I'm inclined to calling this a syntax error. The example the standard provides explicitly comments that the error line doesn't reference a template id, but that's not what the paragraph refers to.

I am working on fixing this issue in Clang, but I'm curious where the problem should be tackled, on the parsing side or the semantic side.

Comment: `template-id` means `template-name < opt-template-argument-list >`

Comment: The textbook definition says this is a syntax error.  I do have to ask, why does it matter what type of error it is? It's an error to use `template` without referring to a template

Comment: If there's no type argument list following the name, there's no need for a template keyword to disambiguate -- you can just use `a.f(t);` regardless of whether `f` ends up being a template or not.

Comment: @NathanOliver I was curious, 1. because, as I read it, the standard doesn't say the name must refer to a template, just that it must be followed by the argument list. 2. Clang doesn't see the error line above is invalid, it currently accepts. So I was trying to determine whether to fix this on the parsing side or the semantic side of things. If the name doesn't have to be a template, then you can check first for the existence of "<" before having to lookup the template name.

Comment: The language definition does not differentiate between syntax errors, semantic errors, or any other kind of errors. They are all just errors. C++ parsing is tightly coupled to the semantics (meaning of the identifiers), any distinction would be arbitrary.

Comment: Personally, I'd call it a syntax error. Missing an expected token seems like pretty much syntax. A semantic error would be more like they have an identifier where needed, *but* the identifier that's present refers to a variable where the name of a type is needed.

Comment: Suppose you have two function names, `fun()` and `fum()`, that are commonly used in various classes in your project. In a certain context, only `fun()` is available, but you type `fum()` instead. Is this a syntax error or a semantic one? Did you intend to call `fun()`, but mis-typed it as `fum()` (a syntax error)? Did you intend to call `fum()` not realizing it is not available in the given context (arguably a semantic error)? *To a large extent, it really doesn't matter what you call it -- it's an error. Fix it; don't bother naming it.*

Comment: *"I'm curious where the problem should be tackled, on the parsing side or the semantic side."* -- Where is it easier to tackle the problem? I doubt many people would complain about how it is detected as long as it is detected.

Comment: The standard just says that a diagnostic is required.    It says nothing about the manner in which that diagnostic is reported or presented (e.g. as informative text or a numeric code, as a semantic or a syntax error, etc).   The manner in which diagnostics are reported/presented is a property of the implementation and how it parses/interprets code and identifies errors.   The utility of diagnostics (e.g. how clearly they describe the cause of an error) is a quality of implementation concern.